# Bash - how to rename a file and keep it in the same directory

Tags: bash, shell

I want to rename certain files, but keep them in their original directory.
If I use

```
mv $file "$2.java"
```

The file gets renamed just fine, but it also gets moved to my current directory, instead of just staying where my script found it.
I need something like this:

```
mv $file "$*/2.java"
```

But I have no idea how to implement it, and can't find anything online

Comment: `mv "$file" "${file%/*}/$2.java"`

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073